# Create 2D array with 2 int arrays

Tags: java

I want to build a 2D matrix with sum of 2 input arrays(by adding row & column elements).

For example, if a is `{1,3,5}` and b is `{4,8}`, I want to build my matrix as so: `[{1,3,5}, {4,7,9}, {8,11,13}]`.

Some more explanation here: [{1,3,5} (this is a), {4,7,9} (4 from b, 7=3+4) (9= 5+4), {8,11,13}]. (8 from b again, then 11= 3+8) (13=5+8). If you draw the first row with a, then draw b as the column aligned with a[0], you could add row element with column element to get the sum matrix.

Is there a more efficient way to do so? I tried to write 2 for-loops which gives a large time and space complexity.

```
 public void BuildMatrix (int[] a, int[] b) {
            int rows = b.length+1;
            int columns = a.length;
            int[][] matrix = new int[b.length+1][a.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < columns-1; i++) {
                matrix[0][i] = a[i];
                for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
                    matrix[j][0] = b[j-1];
                    matrix[j][i+1] = b[j-1] + a[i+1];
                }
            } }
```

Comment: Could you describe algorithm? I can't see why you should give such result: what should you add.

Comment: Ok. I tried to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are input arrays to be of any possible size? If you know size ahead of time you can optimize that.

You are computing `rows` and `columns` twice:

```
        int rows = b.length+1;
        int columns = a.length;
        int[][] matrix = new int[b.length+1][a.length];
```

so why not:

```
        int rows = b.length+1;
        int columns = a.length;
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];
```

likewise you can factor out `b[j-1]` here (but compiler likely does the same anyway):

```
                matrix[j][0] = b[j-1];
                matrix[j][i+1] = b[j-1] + a[i+1];
```

Those are extremely minor bits though.

You should look into the broader picture and try parallelizing `BuildMatrix` calls if it's called a lot. You would then prepare a set of inputs for multiple `BuildMatrix` calls, and run them all on multiple processor cores (in parallel).

Comment: Make sense. Little things make difference. I'll try to write my code thinking about these in the future.

Comment: @M-M there are java libraries that use specialized processor instructions for matrix addition, multiplication, etc. (e.g. http://jblas.org/) wherever they are available. You might want to use it instead of inventing your own if you can.